# DomPDF não carrega gráfico da minha pagina html

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-charts

Boa tarde guys,

Estou com um problema onde meu pdf não carrega meu html...

Controller:

```
function pdf()
    {
      $this->load->library('pdf');
      $data = $this->input->post('input');



        $file_name = 'Dortech.pdf';

        $html  = $data;

        $pdf = new Pdf();
        $pdf->load_html($html);
        $pdf->render();
        $pdf->stream($file_name, array("Attachment" => false));

    }
```

porem quando eu dou um echo na minha váriavel $data ele aparece o html que fiz requerimento.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizei a função getImageURI(), pois o domPDf não suporta a extensão dos gráficos... Sendo assim transformei em imagem e consegui trazer para o PDF.

Comment: Olá Diego, como vc fez? Estou precisando de um exemplo.